# VMWare Horizon Client upgrade, breaks all C# / database applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, vmware

This is arguably the most critical issue our company has ever had.

Our users were previously using **VMWare Horizon Client v3.1.0** with Windows 7.  Since upgrading to **v3.5.2**, all of our in-house WinForms or Office Addin applications which access any of our SQL Server databases don't work anymore.

As soon as the C# code hits this line...

```
MikesDataContext dc = new MikesDataContext()
```

..there is now about an 800-second (13m 40s) delay before *anything happens*.  Even if the connection string is complete rubbish, that line hangs for 800 seconds before throwing an error.

But once this delay has happened *once*, it'll never happen again, using that instance of the application.

Oh, and if the user has Local Admin rights, this problem doesn't happen at all.

[Question truncated.]

Comment: Wierd issue, never seen it before. Seeing as local admin or fresh install fixes it I'd say it smells like the update messed up the permissions somewhere. Check if normal users are allowed to read the app/web.config file. That they are allowed to execute all parts of the .net framework. If that is not it I would get a debug compiled version of one of your apps and run it, attach the visual studio debugger and attempt to debug the `MikesDataContext` constructor. Out of curiosity: if you do nothing and wait the 15 minutes. Does the app work as expected or crash?

Comment: @NickOtten: If we wait, it does (eventually) run normally.  It's odd though, isn't it.  If an upgrade has messed up part of the .Net Framework files, why would it work correctly when run as a Local Admin ?  And I can't step into the MikesDataContext constructor (can I ?)

Comment: If the update removed the read/execute permissions from some of the dll's of the .net framework (the one with the sql driver in this case) it can lead to some very dodgy results. But as you said: eventually it runs. So the .net framework can't be damaged or it would never work. `MikesDataContext` is a entity framework I'm assuming. You can debug those (just hit f11 when hitting the line). You might have to disable the 'just my code' setting in the VS debugger options though (not sure, I noticed I have it disabled). The local Admin thing is still a mysterie to me.

Comment: you should post your own solution as an answer an accept it, otherwise this question looks unsolved.

Comment: Good point.  Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We raised an issue with VMWare themselves, and they admitted that when you uninstall Horizon Client 3.1 or 3.2, it removes a few registry entries which it shouldn't have.

They knew about this problem, but when you install a later version, they made no attempt to fix it in your registry. They do mention this problem in the following Knowledge Base article, but none of my Google searches stumbled across this article.

[VMware - Launching applications requires elevated permissions](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2105977)

Anyway... here's the solution.

If your company hits this problem, the fix is to go into the following registry path on a "working" machine, export the registry entries, and restore them onto a "broken" machine.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel
```

Reboot your laptop, and afterwards, the problem goes away.

(I need a beer...)